# Pandas install - EnvironmentError

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to install pandas in python 3.7 and got the I got the problem when trying to use '`pip install pandas`'

```
Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: 
HTTPSConnectionPool(host='files.pythonhosted.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: 
/packages/45/12/1e1ba99fb65df9f7f3724d3232feef35cc044d18604d57492d561e90219f/pandas-0.23.0.tar.gz 
(Caused by ProtocolError('Connection aborted.', 
 ConnectionResetError(10054, 'An existing connection was forcibly closed by the 
 remote host', None, 10054, None)))
```

[image]

Comment: Check whether you need to add any proxy ?

Comment: Have you tried accessing the site directly? `https://files.pythonhosted.org/`

Comment: What's the version of your **pip**?

Comment: @Daniel M I use google chrome and it can't reach the site directly https://files.pythonhosted.org/

Comment: @Mauro Baraldi my pip version is pip 10.0.1

Comment: @kvmahesh I'm a newbie, can you show me how to know whether I need to add any proxy?

Comment: @Daniel M I got it, it because of my school network. Thanks mate